# Can't get conversationUpdate activity with the Enhanced Direct Line Authentication Features

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I'm trying to use the Enhanced Direct Line Authentication Features so I can get rid of the Magic Number.

I just enabled this option and added the trusted origin (https://mychatbot.azurewebsites.net/   <- Not the real one, but is stored on Azure) to the DirectLine.

Then on the code of the website I request the token:

```
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  uri: 'https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate',
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer MyDirectLineSecret"
  },
  json: {
      User: {
        id: "dl_" + uuid.v4(),
        name: "UserTest"
      },
      trustedOrigins: ["https://mychatbot.azurewebsites.net/"]

}
```

Then I make the request for the token:

```
const response = await rp(options);
const token = response.token;
```

Like that I have the token and when I go to my bot website (https://mychatbot.azurewebsites.net/) I don't send the updateActivity request and can't send the user the welcome message.

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong about the DirectLine configuration.

Is there anything I should change? I'm using an app service for the bot framework and inserting directly the webchat uri in the trusted origins. I don't know if I am wrong in the request of the token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't doing anything wrong. This is a known issue in the DirectLine Connector Service, and the development team is currently working to resolve the issue. Essentially, the second conversation update is not being sent because the user id in the token is causing an error. For more details, checkout this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2120) on Github. I'll be sure to let you know when it is resolved as well. 
In the meantime, I would recommend taking a look at the Web Chat [Backchannel Welcome Event](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/15.d.backchannel-send-welcome-event) sample.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information. I just did it like the Backchannel Welcome Event and worked flawlessly. But right now I have another issue. Before I was able to connect to the user's conversation as an "Agent" with the Directline Secret, conversationId and watermark="0", but now, with the enhanced Direct Line Authentication Features enabled I can't join anymore. There is a way to "join" to a existing conversation with a second user with the enhance caracteristic?

Comment: The problem I think is the same as this one: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-docs/issues/412

Comment: Glad to hear the backchannel welcome event worked for you! At the moment you have to add the user id to the token request to reload the conversation. The development team has found a fix for the user id bug and should release the fix early next week.

Comment: @DavidCG The fix should be rolling out now. Marking the solution as accepted serves the greater Stack Overflow community and anyone with a similar question. If you feel my answer was sufficient, please "accept" it. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Comment: Where can I see the fix report? I'm trying but still getting the error "Missing user ID". Thanks

Comment: The report is in a private repo. What HTTP client are you using? Try setting the content type in the header to ‘application/json’. You might need to stringify the user object and I believe the ‘u’ in user is lowercase.